# How do I compile the following flex file in C++ with auxiliary functions

Tags: c++, g++, flex-lexer

I have the following lex.l file.

```
 %{
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #define AND 1
 #define BEGINN 2

 &}

 /* regular definitions */
 ws     [ \t\n]+
 letter [A-Za-z]
 /* more declarations */

 %%

 {ws}
 {id}       {yylval = (int) storeLexeme(); return(ID);}
 {num}      {yylval = (int) storeInt(); return(NUM);}
 /* more rules */
 %%

 int storeLexeme() {
 /* function implementation */
 }

 int storeInt() {
 /* function implementation */
 }
```

I run this file with flex, and it compiles with gcc but reports the following errors with g++.

```
 lex.l:110: error: `storeLexeme' undeclared (first use this function)
 lex.l:110: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function   
 it appears in.)
 lex.l:111: error: `storeInt' undeclared (first use this function)
 lex.l: In function `int storeLexeme()':
 lex.l:117: error: `int storeLexeme()' used prior to declaration
 lex.l: In function `int storeInt()':
 lex.l:121: error: `int storeInt()' used prior to declaration
```

How do I resolve these errors?

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare them first. Change the first section:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define AND 1
#define BEGINN 2

int storeLexeme(void);
int storeInt(void);
%}
```

Also, if you only need these functions in that one file (which is probably the case if they're not declared in a header), you should probably be declaring them `static`, or in an anonymous namespace if you're using C++.